# Кодировка строки

Tags: java, android, listview

Создаю что-то вроде mp3 плеера. Есть массив всех песен, вывожу в `ListView`. Некоторые песни выводятся иероглифами. `getbytes()` не помогает. Может кто знает решение проблемы?

Comment: А откуда у вас берётся название? Судя по всему, вы достаёте его не вполне правильно.

Comment: Этот вопрос уже был решен. Стоит поискать, прежде, чем задавать вопросы:)) Вариант 1 - справа внизу в Android Studio указать кодировку. Вариант 2 - правильный - брать данные из strings.xml

Comment: @Rishka вы так уверены? может автор читает из тегов файла и выводит?

Comment: Очевидно, проблема в charset. Но без кода невозможно определить в чем ваша конкретная ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону `getBytes(Charset)`, а именно примерно так:

```
public String convert(String inString, String inCharset, String outCharset) {
    byte[] bytes=inString.getBytes(inCharset);
    return new String(bytes, outCharset);
}
```

Например: `convert(s, "cp1251", "utf-8")` //перекодировка из кодировки Windows в UTF-8

Просто `getBytes()` не поможет, потому что он дает байты в текущей кодировке (локали) JVM

Comment: А в какой кодировке маленькая а в byte равна 108?